# How to call a method every 2 weeks in PHP without a Crontab

Tags: php

I want to update the div in html to display different contents every week with just php and without the use of cron.
How will it be posssible to achieve it ? The following code is for activating the code every 2 month on the 10nth day
but I guess the logic will be different. If possible some hint or example will be great ! I will love to hear from you!

```
    // check if current day is 10th and month is an even number
if (date('d')==10 && date('m') % 2 == 0) {
    // get todays-date (format: yyyymmdd)
    $today = date('Ymd'); 
    // get info about last run
    $last_run = variable_get('my_last_run', 0);
    // check last run was not today
    if ($last_run!=$today) {
        // set last run to today
        variable_set('my_last_run', $today);

        /* Place your code here */

    }
}
```

Comment: You need a cron or something to trigger that page/script.  PHP won't trigger on its own.

Comment: Look at `date('W')`. This will give you the week number in the year.

Comment: how can I do with the above code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just updated your example, now it will work every next Monday:

```
$weekInYearNumber = (int)date('W');
$weekDayNumber = (int)date('w');
if ($weekDayNumber === 1 && $weekInYearNumber % 2 == 0) {
    // Rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: With this every time this condition gets called it will check if it's the 2nd week? I never tried it but it looks awesome! Thank you for the help !

Comment: Happy that it helps you!)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to use a cron job for that (which would be the easiest and recommended solution), you can create a PHP script that spends most of the time sleeping, and wakes up to check the date and run whatever you need.

If you don't care about dates and just want to run it every two weeks, you can make it sleep like this:

```
 sleep(14*24*60*60);
```

Have your script execute your code after that, and put all that inside an infinite loop. Then just run the script from the console so it doesn't have an execution time limit.

Take into account that the script may stop running for different reasons, for example when servers reboot, so you should monitor the process and re-run it automatically if it's not running or on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
  function runEveryWeek(){
     sleep(/*for 2 weeks*/);
     runEveryWeek();
  }
```

Comment: No, that won't work at all. PHP scripts running from a web server cannot run for multiple weeks at a time -- they will be killed long before that.

Answer (score 0):

With purpose to display different contents every week, you can use this

```
$week = (int)date('W');
$odd = ($week % 2) === 0;
if ($ood) {
    // First week.
} else {
    // Second week.
}
```

Comment: Will this code work even if the browser gets refreshed? And how will I add a condition to check the 3rd and the 4th week ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it will) Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ? Your web page will open for 2 month ?

You can apply one logic

Just save next cron date in database. so your logic will like

```
<?php

if($databaseDate == date()){
   //Perform acetion here
   // Save your next date here
}
?>
```

I hope this will solve your problem

If you don't want to do this then you can use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

For pm2 you need ssh access of the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it quickly, you can count weeks since the first of january 2018 (because it was monday: any other year started with a monday will be ok), and then check if that number is odd or even:

```
      $diffBetweenNowAndFirstJan2018 = time() - strtotime("2018-01-01");
      $numberOfWeeksSinceFirstJan2018 = floor($diffBetweenNowAndFirstJan2018 / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
      $isNumberOfWeeksOdd = ($numberOfWeeksSinceFirstJan2018 % 2 == 1)

      if($isNumberOfWeeksOdd){
            // it's other week time
    }
```

In one line:

```
     if( ( (floor((time() - strtotime("2018-01-01")) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7))) % 2 == 1) ){
            // it's other week time
    }
```

You should not use date('W') as Vladmir says, because between new year's eve you could get two "odd" week consecutively.